# Returning a generic class based upon roles

Tags: c#

ON the page I'm currently working on I need to return two different class types based upon roles.

This is the public

```
public class psdata
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        etc...
}
```

This is the management

```
public class cpsdata
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Customer { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        etc...
}
```

how can I create a function that will return the class I need when making, for example, a list.

```
 List<psdata> ld = new List<psdata>();
```

Where psdata can be either psdata or cpsdata?

Comment: The question could be more general: how do I declare a variable or parameter so that it accepts more than one type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your classes need to share a common **interface** or a common **base class**. Below is an example **implementing an interface**, can be also made by **extending a class**

```
public interface IData { /** common elements **/ void Foo(); }

public class psdata : IData
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        etc...
        public void Foo() {
             // psdata specific
        }
}

public class cpsdata : IData
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Customer { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        etc...
        public void Foo() {
             // cpsdata specific
        }
}
```

**Note:** `Foo` can be everything that behave different.

Now you can create a list of `IData` and return it.

```
public List<IData> Elements() {
    List<IData> ld = new List<IData>();
    ld.Add(new psdata());
    ld.Add(new cpsdata());
    return ld;
}
```

---

If you want to use some specific properties/methods of elements you can make **unboxing**

1) Using `is` keyword and after that make a **cast** to that *type*.

```
foreach(var element in ld) {
   if(element is psdata) { 
        var elementPSData = (psdata) element;
        /** do something **/
   }
```

2) Using `as` keyword (this make a cast an return null if the element `is` not that *type*).

```
   var elementData = element as cpsdata;
   if(elemntData != null) {
      /** do something **/
   }
```

Comment: You might also want to add that the page can use the `is` operator on the `List` object to figure out which derived type is being used.

Comment: You still have to cast it to your concrete class to get access to the non IDATA properties.  And the question said "two different classes"

Comment: Sure, but the point is that you *can* define methods and struct properties common to both types in the interface... or just use an abstract class if you require more structure. Using `object` gives you none of that.

Comment: What if the classes where boat, cheers, and popsicle.  Now you gotta figure what they have in common.  I'm not saying there is anything wrong with the interface, or base class, just that no matter how you slice it you are going to type check and cast.

Comment: @Vincent this classes have something in common `Address` and `ID`. It's enough to find something in common and extract it in a *common place*.

Comment: More importantly, there is likely to be common *functionality*.  A better implementation would be to provide a method in the interface that implements that  functionality without the rest of the code needing to have knowledge of the types at all.  In this case, maybe it would be `RenderForm()` perhaps?

Comment: @SteveCzetty you are right, a common method in interface will be a very good idea

Comment: This is some great stuff. excuse the n00b question. If I now have an Elements() now how do I add in data to it?   Say from a linq query. ex: var q = from  p in db.propserties select new psdata {/** psdata elements **/}

Comment: @Prescient you can use `List` method [`AddRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this. `ld.AddRange(q)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an abstract base class from which you can derive both the `cpsdata` and `psdata` classes and then you can add instances of both the `cpsdata` and `psdata` classes to the list containing objects of the type from which you derived.

P.S That class naming convention is horrible.

Answer (score -4):

If you really want a quick fix

```
List<Object> ld = new List<Object>();
foreach(Object obj in ld)
{
  //check object type and take appropriate action
}
```

There are obviously a lot of ways to solve this on the generic side i.e. create an interface or base class and a generic method where T: some object, however, you will still have to check type for the additional properties.

Comment: Yuck. To actually use properties or methods of any `object` in the list this way, you'd have to first type check the list, then cast each object? No thanks; just use adricadar's interface solution.

Comment: You have to cast regardless.